# Getting parameters from a JcomboBox

Tags: java, swing, serial-port, jcombobox

Below is my best attempt at an SSCCE. You will need RXTX Library for this to work. My objective is to set the serial port parameters based on the selections made in the combobox. Please can someone point me in the right direction?

This looks after the opening of the Comport:

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class TwoWaySerialComm {

SerialPort serialPort;

public TwoWaySerialComm() {
super();
}

public synchronized void connect(String portName) throws Exception {

CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {

    System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
} else {
    CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),
            2000);

    if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, 
                   SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
        (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

    } else {
        System.out
                .println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this.");
    }
}
}

public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable {
OutputStream out;

public SerialWriter(OutputStream out) {
    this.out = out;
    }

public void run() {
    try {
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = System.in.read()) > -1) {
            this.out.write(c);
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this is the GIU:

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


public class SSCCE extends JFrame {

public TwoWaySerialComm twoWaySerCom;

public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        try {
            SSCCE frame = new SSCCE();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

}

public SSCCE() {
initComponents();
twoWaySerCom = new TwoWaySerialComm();

}

private void initComponents(){              
setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 550, 250));
setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ);
setType(Type.POPUP);
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
setTitle("Alarm Generator");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 118, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 23, 0, 0};
gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);


comPortcomboBox = new JComboBox();
comPortcomboBox.setEnabled(true);
GridBagConstraints gbc_comPortcomboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_comPortcomboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc_comPortcomboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_comPortcomboBox.gridx = 1;
gbc_comPortcomboBox.gridy = 2;
getContentPane().add(comPortcomboBox, gbc_comPortcomboBox);
Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
  CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();

  if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
          comPortcomboBox.addItem(cpi.getName());

    }

  }

 comPortcomboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            comPortcomboBoxActionPerformed(evt);
        }

public void comPortcomboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    comPortcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
    comPortcomboBox.setSelectedItem(portName);

 }

});


JComboBox baudRateComboBox = new JComboBox(baudRates);
baudRateComboBox.setSelectedIndex(2);       
GridBagConstraints gbc_baudRateComboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_baudRateComboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc_baudRateComboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_baudRateComboBox.gridx = 1;
gbc_baudRateComboBox.gridy = 3;
getContentPane().add(baudRateComboBox, gbc_baudRateComboBox);
GridBagConstraints gbc_alarm2Button = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_alarm2Button.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc_alarm2Button.gridx = 9;
gbc_alarm2Button.gridy = 3;

openComportButton = new JButton("Open");
GridBagConstraints gbc_openComportButton = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_openComportButton.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
gbc_openComportButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
gbc_openComportButton.gridx = 0;
gbc_openComportButton.gridy = 7;
getContentPane().add(openComportButton, gbc_openComportButton);

openComportButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        openComportButtonActionPerformed(evt);
    }
    public synchronized void openComportButtonActionPerformed(
            java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {

                    try {
                        twoWaySerCom.connect(portName);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 
            });
        }

public javax.swing.JButton openComportButton;   
public javax.swing.JComboBox comPortcomboBox;
public javax.swing.JComboBox baudRatecomboBox;

String portName ="COM4";    
String[] baudRates = { "2400", "4800", "9600", "14400", "19200", "38400",     "56000", "115200"  };

}
```

Comment: [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, in your `openComportButtonActionPerformed` method, you need to ask the `comPortcomboBox` and `baudRatecomboBox` for their selected values

```
String port = (String)comPortcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
String rate = (String)baudRatecomboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

You then need to check to see if the values are valid...

```
if (port != null && rate != null) {
    //...
}
```

Then you need to pass those values to your `twoWaySerCom`

```
public void openComportButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {
    String port = (String)comPortcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String rate = (String)baudRatecomboBox.getSelectedItem();
    if (port != null && rate != null) {
        try {
            twoWaySerCom.connect(portName, rate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But you'll need to modify your `connect` method to support a baud rate value

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer.  It looks so familiar that i must have tried to do this already and when it didn't work i removed it and tried something else,  I receive an error at
    String port = (String)comPortcomboBox.getSelectedValue();

The method getSelectedValue() is undefined for the type JComboBox

Comment: Sorry, it's `getSelectedItem` :P

Comment: Awsome. I tested with port to begin with and it works fine,  Then i tried:
`twoWaySerCom.connect(port, rate, data, stop, parity);` and this in my connect method:
`public synchronized void connect(String port, String rate, String data, String stop, String parity)`now i get a null pointer here: `String rate = (String)baudRatecomboBox.getSelectedItem();`

Comment: Your shadowing the `baudRatecomboBox` variable, change `JComboBox baudRateComboBox = new JComboBox(baudRates);` to `baudRateComboBox = new JComboBox(baudRates);`

Comment: Thats brilliant,  I have fallen for that before and changed the majority of them, I just missed a few so i will go away and learn the differences. 

 one last problem, `serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,  SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);` only allows integers, so my thought of doing this `serialPort.setBaudBase(rate);` wont work.  Can you offer another pointer?